# Mobile App GetIdentityAsync no value

Tags: azure, facebook-login, azure-mobile-services, google-signin

I have this code from Azure Services Mobile App, API custom controller. The result always the same "1:1". I test with all identity providers, google, facebook, twitter, and Microsoft Account, except AD. I think the problem is the call to GetIdentityAsync. Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetIdentityInfo()
    {
        var user = (MobileAppUser)this.User;            

        string str = "";
        string Provider = "YES", UserId = "NO";
        try
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                Provider = "1"; UserId = "1";
                var microsoftCredentials = await user.GetIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>();
                if (microsoftCredentials != null && microsoftCredentials.Claims != null)
                {
                    Provider = "MICROSOFT";
                    UserId = microsoftCredentials.UserId;
                }

                Provider = "2"; UserId = "2";
                var googleCredentials = await user.GetIdentityAsync<GoogleCredentials>();
                if (googleCredentials != null && googleCredentials.Claims != null)
                {
                    Provider = "GOOGLE";
                    UserId = googleCredentials.UserId;
                }

                Provider = "3"; UserId = "3";
                var facebookCredentials = await user.GetIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>();
                if (facebookCredentials != null && facebookCredentials.Claims != null)
                {
                    Provider = "FACEBOOK";
                    UserId = facebookCredentials.UserId;
                }

                Provider = "4"; UserId = "4";
                var twitterCredentials = await user.GetIdentityAsync<TwitterCredentials>();
                if (twitterCredentials != null && twitterCredentials.Claims != null)
                {
                    Provider = "TWITTER";
                    UserId = twitterCredentials.UserId;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Provider = "NONE"; UserId = "NULL";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            str = "ERROR";
        }
        finally
        {
            str = Provider + ":" + UserId;
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: The error is in GetIdentityAsync call. Generate a UriFormat error in mscorlib.dll. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We receive support from Microsoft Support Engineer Adrian Fernandez Garcia, and send an example that worked OK. The unique difference was that EMA_RuntimeUrl must be created manually in mobile app in azure portal in Application Properties, and assigned to Gateway address.

Actually this value is created automatically and don't have to create it manually.

This gave us the error `URIFormat NULL value`.

All is working OK now.

Thanks to Microsoft for the support.