# How to get basic user information in an Azure Mobile Web App?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, azure, mobile

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, and I'd like to implement its authentication features based on FaceBook and Azure. The authentication itself work, but I have not found the way to get basic user info from it (name, email...)

```
var user = await DependencyService.Get<IMobileClient>()
            .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```

On server side

```
 var mobileAppUser = (MobileAppUser)User;
 var facebookCredentials = 
     user.GetIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>().Result;
```

mobileAppUser exists, but facebookCredentials is always null.

My backend on Azure is a new mobile web app written in .net. All of its features working great, except this authentication question. I could not find the proper way to solve this problem on server side or on client side. Pls. note, my question is about the new way of Azure mobile apps, not the old classic one.

Would you be so kind to help me? Any sample code or documentation are warmly welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don´t know if it can help you but I feel it can: http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/how-to-using-facebook-to-authenticate-with-web-api-2-in-a-native-mobile-application/    or  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx  or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463125/azure-mobile-service-with-facebook-auth-get-user-info  .  I hope they can drive you to a solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks my friend I read several doc including these ones, but they did not help solved my problem.

Comment: You´re welcome. I´m sad they didn´t helped you, good luck.

Comment: @Tom You should look at this [details article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/) as well (If you haven't yet). There might be multiple things that are not yet clear from the question. Like on server side it should be MobileServiceUser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569643/mobile-app-getidentityasync-no-value

Comment: Thanks Navum, it had been checked, and no problem with it.

Answer (score 5):

*Too long for a comment*

If you check out the implementation of [`GetIdentityAsync`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication/MobileAppUser.cs#L57), you'll see the following:

- It checks if the user is authenticated (you said that the user is authenticated so there's no problem here)
- reads the `"EMA_RuntimeUrl"` from the config (it's not null, because then you'd get an exception)
- it check if the token from the provider is valid or not. If not, this returns `null`.

I believe this is the issue you are running into. A quick search on this issue brings you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569643/mobile-app-getidentityasync-no-value) SO question.

So have you created an EMA_RuntimeUrl manually in mobile app in azure portal in Application Properties, and assigned to Gateway address?

Comment: Thanks! EMA_RuntimeUrl settings is created automatically, when I created the app in Azure. I did not change anything. Its value is the gateway url, and when opening this url in a browser, it says 'Gateway is up'.

Comment: So, I think this setting is ok, and my problem still exists.

Comment: It definitely seems like a configuration problem. Your code is correct. So without any additional information it would be tough to say anything. [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-migrating-from-mobile-services.md#authentication-considerations) migration help mentions to "Add the gateway's /signin-* endpoints as an additional redirect URI for each provider." and has an _[AZURE.NOTE]_, which might also apply for Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Using an async call you should wait the operation is completed and after completion the result will be available. You can do this in many way but in this case the most natural would be:

```
var facebookCredentials = await user.GetIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>();
// Here you can use your facebookCredentials variable:
```

Comment: Waiting for task's result also waits for the completion.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still worth a try. Never know the implementation details.

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried it earlier, like several other trivial things.

Comment: OK, then I am going to delete this answer to reduce the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know can this really helps, but I'll try. As I understand, you are using asp.net identity with facebook middlewarefor this. I use this also, but with google oauth middleware instead of facebook. If I'm right, this should be the solution

If so, when you make authentication request with middleware you specified callback url which you will be redirected after successful authentication process with your provider (facebook). To ask for external authentication you call `ChallangeResult` with this url specified. When you reached this callback, you can use `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` method from `IAuhtnticationManager` interface as the first step in your callback method. To get `IAuthenticationManager` instance you can read  `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication` property. After this you can get all necessary info about user as `IIdentity` implementation - `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns `ExternalIdentity` instance

Hope that helps